# installation of graphics driver for lenovo Y700

Tags: nvidia

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Y700 15ISK 80NW Notebook

[image: my lenovo y700]

and I installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.1, all good but not the graphics card.

It has NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M - 4096 MB. I tried to install `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.35.run` but there is a conflict with "driver nvidia nouveau" so I uninstall nouveau and install `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.35.run` but when I reboot my laptop, I have a black screen.

What is the correct method to install the nvidia driver?